# Multiply scalar in matrix with matrix in tensor in the corresponding position by numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Pardon me for possibly an easy question.

If given a matrix U with shape [L, L], and a tensor V with shape [L, L, m, n], I want a numpy way to calculate the multiplication between the scalar in U and the matrix in tensor in the corresponding position.

For example,I want the following operation

```
U[i,j] * V[i, j, :, :]
```

across the whole index at the same time.

Noted that the U[i,j] is the scalar in the location(i, j) in matrix U, and the V[i, j, :, :] is the matrix in the location(i, j) in tensor V.

Thanks in advance!

Update #1

Maybe the description above isn't clear. Then I make it clearly again.

Given a matrix U and a tensor V like:

```
U = np.arange(2*2).reshape(2, 2)
V = np.arange(2*2*3*4).reshape(2, 2, 3, 4)
```

And I want the tensor result R, whose element are following:

```
R[i,j,:,:] = U[i, j] * V[i, j, :, :]                      (1)
```

e.g.

```
U[0, 0] = 0
V[0, 0] = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
                 [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
                 [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

And

```
R[0, 0] = U[0, 0] * V[0, 0] = np.zeros((3, 4))  (for short)
```

Another example:

```
U[0, 1] = 1
V[0, 1] = array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
                 [16, 17, 18, 19],
                 [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

And

```
R[0, 1] = U[0, 1] * V[0, 1] = V[0, 1]  (for short)
```

The process will across the whole index.

Noted that the index i and j is same in (1)

So my goal is to complete the process above only with few code, instead of a loop.

Comment: `U[:L,:L,None,None]*V`?

Comment: @Divakar    I'm sorry. The shape of U isn't the [m, n]. The shape of U should be [L, L]. Therefore, U[i, j] * V[i, j, :, :]  can make sense.

Comment: Then, simply : `U[...,None,None]*V`.

Comment: But the result I want is a tensor R, which R[i, j, :, :] = U[i, j] * V[i, j, :, :]. And the shape of R is [L, L, m, n]

Comment: Did you try out the suggested code - `U[...,None,None]*V`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried the code. But I got the shape I didn't want.

Comment: Add mcve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: I have tried my best to make the question clearly.@Divakar

Comment: And `U[...,None,None]*V` gives us the expected output. I don't see what's the issue.

Comment: Oh. It's my fault. After I reinitialize the whole variable and try the operation you have suggested again, I found the operation make sense. That do help me a lot. Thank a lot for your time.